# xlwings range.api.validation.add throws com_error -2146827284

Tags: python, pywin32, xlwings

I'm trying to add data validation to an Excel worksheet range using xlwings:

```
def set_validation(rng):
    """Add data validation to the given range"""
    rng.value = "linear_benefit"
    rng.api.validation.delete()
    # xlValidateList = 3
    rng.api.validation.add(3, None, None, 
        "linear_benefit,linear_cost,sigmoid_benefit,sigmoid_cost", None)
```

when I run this, it stops at the last line with error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

the error number -2146827284, from what I've read, seems to be a general "name not found" error. VBA works fine with this:

```
rng.Validation.Add Type:=3, _
    Formula1:="linear_benefit,linear_cost,sigmoid_benefit,sigmoid_cost")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem comes from passing None to the second and third arguments of the `add` method. The revised line below worked for me.

```
rng.api.Validation.add(3,1,3,"linear_benefit,linear_cost,sigmoid_benefit,sigmoid_cost")
```

Comment: I finally got time to check this and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

xlwings has made the VBA constants available in python. To make your code more readable, therefore, you could do something like this:

```
from xlwings import constants
validation_list = "linear_benefit,linear_cost,sigmoid_benefit,sigmoid_cost"
dv_type = constants.DVType.xlValidateList
dv_alertstyle = constants.DVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop
dv_operator = constants.FormatConditionOperator.xlEqual
rng.api.Validation.Add(dv_type, dv_alertstyle, dv_operator, validation_list)
```

Another gotcha I encountered is that in my locale, the commas in the validation list should be replaced by semicolons. I ended up writing a small function for this:

```
def set_validation_list(rng, validation_list):
    if validation_list is None:
        validation_list = [' ']
    if not isinstance(validation_list, list):
        raise TypeError('trying to set a validation list, but input is not a list')
    dv_type = constants.DVType.xlValidateList
    dv_alertstyle = constants.DVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop
    dv_operator = constants.FormatConditionOperator.xlEqual
    rng.api.Validation.Add(dv_type, dv_alertstyle, dv_operator, ';'.join(validation_list))
```